# Laravel - Deleting several models with the same signature datetime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have Model `A` which has multiple relationships with other models, let's say `B`, `C`, `D`.

The `A` has many `B` ...  Models.

When I'm deleting `A` i need also to delete `B` ... related models (I mean soft deleting).

I could use a query to UPDATE all models like this in `boot()` method:

```
A::deleted(function (A $a) {
    $now = new Carbon();
    B::where('a_id', '=', $a->id)->update([B::DELETED_AT, $now]);
    C::where('a_id', '=', $a->id)->update([C::DELETED_AT, $now]);
    D::where('a_id', '=', $a->id)->update([D::DELETED_AT, $now]);
});
```

but I don't want to do it that way because if I add events to these models in the future, they will never run and I will be forced to edit this script, which seems to me a violation of O from SOLID.

With that in mind, I changed it to eloquent:

```
A::deleted(function (A $a) {
    $b = $a->b;
    foreach ($b as $x) {
        $x->delete();
    }
});
```

But that also raises a problem. Apart from the fact that it takes much longer, each of these models is removed individually, and therefore at a different time. The difference between first deleted model and the last one is a few seconds, and it seems to me that this may cause further problems in the future, considering the fact that from the user's point of view, he performs this action with one click, so why have they been deleted in other time?

I could solved that problem with ... update like in first time, but I will be do 'the same' action twice.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Have you thought of using foreign key constrains ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints
Example: `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')>onDelete('cascade');`
So if you deleted a user, let's say with id `1` , every record related to him `user_id: 1` will be deleted too.

Comment: I don't want to permanently delete records from the database, but mark them as deleted with time signature delated_at

Comment: Yes, that's easy. Just add in your model `use SoftDeletes` and in your migrations 
`$table->softDeletes();`

Comment: I've already done it, what you wrote does not solve the problem, it is.